# Ajax call json undefined Object : object

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, mysqli

the json value keeps returning unidentified or it doesnt display at all

PHP CODE

```
$index=0;

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

    $index++;
    $data=array(

        array(

            $index=>$row['menuName']
        )

    );


  }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

JQUERY AJAX

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
              $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {loadpage: 'table'},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'addtable.php',
                    success: function(data){        

                        $('.navbar ul').append('<li><a href="#" class="table">'+data[0]+'</a></li>');
                } 
                }); //ajax request
             });
    </script>
```

The json is fine it displays in the right format. When i change my jquery to data[0] it displays object Object and if i do data[1 or higher] it gives me undefined. I dont know what im doing wrong i even tried it do this: data[0].1 and it displays nothing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Becuase data[0] is an object not value and u try to print as a value.

Comment: `console.log(data);` outputs what?

Comment: how many values are you expecting anyway? do you only need one value? or rows of values?

Comment: i didnt include this but i basically want it to grab data form the database and create a new link everytime i still havent used the $.each function because i was trying to see if the json will output what i wanted.

Comment: The console log actually shows me the value i wanted. But why cant it do that in my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is to fix the PHP script part which responds to the request.

Create a valid JSON string response. The simpliest way is first to create a container (an array).

Then second is the to continually push fetched rows in there. Then finally use `json_encode` in the end.

**Don't encode while inside the loop:**

Simple example:

```
// initialize container
$data = array();

// the pushing of rows
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $data[] = $row; // push the whole row
}

// finally, echo it to into a JSON string
echo json_encode($data);
// don't put me inside the WHILE
```

PHP Note: *If this is `mysqli`, I'd suggest use the **`->fetch_assoc()`** instead or just simply **`->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` flag**.*

In your AJAX script, just handle the response as you normally would:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {loadpage: 'table'},
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'addtable.php',
        success: function(data){
            // every each row, create an LI element with an anchor
            $.each(data, function(index, element){
                $('.navbar ul').append('<li><a href="#" class="table">'+element.menuName+'</a></li>');
                // just use the column names as the properties in your data response that came from PHP
            });       


        } 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

If this runs, this should yield something into a markup like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="table">Table1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="table">Table2</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="table">Table4</a>
</li>
```

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work. Thanks alot for the help though

Comment: shouldn't the `id="table"` end up as `class="table"`?

Comment: @NaderBesada modify when necessary, use `$.each` when you're expecting multiple rows and creating the markup that you want in that kind of fashion there's the answer already to guide you through into completing it

Comment: The user enters the menu names in the db. I just need to pull them out and put each menu as a link in my nav bar

Comment: @NaderBesada then do that, use `.val()` when needed, put that input inside `data: { userinput: blah blah }` in your AJAX request, and process the request inside PHP, `$userinput = $_GET['userinput']` and so on...

Comment: @NaderBesada how many data are there inside `success: function(data)`? use `console.log(data)` before the `$.each`, if you are indeed getting all the rows you need. `echo json_encode($data);` should echo all the data formatted into a JSON string. just make sure you have more than one row in your db table though